# Replicate Action on Remote Form

Tags: c#, forms, server, client

I know it seems odd, but I'm trying to write an application where there are multiple clients which after connecting to a server they share the same form. So if a client validate a checkbox, in the other clients form the checkbox become validated.
What's the simplest/best approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a Database or at least you can create a file in the server side, I would put there the centralized and "updated" state of the checkbox and any other state for that matter and then make the clients ask for the status every X seconds with a timer, like polling. It might not be the best way but I think is the easiest. Note: Care about simultaneous changes, transactions and dirty reads of info.

Other option would be to allow clients to communicate with each other and then you could send a message to all the clients when a change happens. This would be more of a subscribers or listeners approach. But you would have to provide more info about your problem and structure to see if this is feasible.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you, I'm going for database solution, simple and working. Thanks again!